# Nature of stock trading at IB

Tags: trading

I’d like to know how a trade takes place for traders at Investment Banks. So when they sell a stock for a client, do they buy the stocks for them and then try to sell it to other party? Or are they merely trying to find someone to buy it (without themselves buying them)? Same for buying stocks for clients: do they sell stocks from their inventory and later replenish or just try to look for someone willing to sell those stocks without themselves actually selling them? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that 99.9% of stock trading through an investment bank is done through an *exchange*, which facilitates all stock transactions. So no, the IB does not buy the stock for you and then sell it to you, they simply put the order on the exchange, the exchange matches your order with someone else who's selling the stock, and the exchange facilitates the transaction. You have no idea who you bought the stock from (in fact, you might have bought stock from *several* counterparties in one transaction).

The other 0.1% *could* be private equity or OTC stocks, which the bank *could* purchase and then re-sell to you if it was in their interest to do so (e.g. if they added a fee on top of the transaction), or they could help line up willing counterparties. But that would be a very small minority of stock transactions,

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified that by IB you meant Investment Banks, let's try a different answer.

Trading desks at an IB are usually set up in different sectors:  Forex, fixed income, equities and commodities. The IB acts as an intermediary b/t clients whether they be individual investors or institutions, earning commissions.  The trades could be in the open market or they could be cross trades where the portfolio manager swaps out one client's holding into another clients account (B/S), eliminating the spreads on both sides of the trade.

IB's also engage in proprietary trading which is when they invest/trade their own money. They can act as a market maker as well, taking the other side of a clients trade.  As an example of how lucrative this can be, one of the traders at Goldman Sachs generated a quarter of a million dollars in gains a few years ago, trading junk bonds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by IB you are referring to Interactive Brokers?  If so, they are merely  the intermediary between buyers and sellers.

Like other brokers in the U.S., they are required by the SEC to provide NBBO (National Best Bid and Offer) which is the best available ask price when buying securities, and the best available bid price when selling securities.

Here's a hypothetical quote for Netflix:

$326.90 x $327.00 with size of 15 x 8

That means that there are 1500 shares being bid for (to buy) at $326.90 and 800 shares being offered for sale at $327.00.  Those are willing participants in the auction. It could be one buyer looking to sell 800 shares or 8 buyers looking to sell 100 shares each.  The number of people is irrelevant - only  the total volume means anything.  If someone were to take out all of the share either bid or asked (1500 or 800) and no one else stepped in with another order at those prices then the quote would change and reflect the next price level of orders in the book.

Investment banks have trading desks that buy and sell securities for their own accounts as well as for clients but that's a different story

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant Investment Banks. I didn't know IB also could mean interactive broker. I'll clarify the question.